# XMLHttpreques onprogress event not called

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, long-polling

Do not confuse `XMLHttprequest.onprogress` with the `XMLHttprequest.upload.onprogress`.

I use this `XMLHttprequest.onprogress` event to handle server input before the long-polling request ends. On the server, the script may look like that:

```
while(condition && timeout condition) {
    if(data available) {
        echo $data;
        flush();
    }
}
```

The javascript onprogress event looks like this:

```
  function onprogressCallback() {     
    //Start at the current position in the input, anything before has already been sent to onData()
    var seektmp = seeker;

    //Loop through the input and seek delimiters
    while(seektmp<_this.http.responseText.length&&!forcedDisconnect) {
      if(_this.http.responseText[seektmp]==_this.delimiter) {
        //If a delimiter has been found, send the fragment before to onData
        var data = _this.http.responseText.substr(seeker,seektmp-seeker); 
        //Only call on nonempty data, empty data are used to keep onprogress event running
        if(data!="")
          _this.onData(data);
        //Skip the original seeker to the end of data that has been read (+1 for delimiter)

        //console.log("DATA!: '",_this.http.responseText.substr(seeker,seektmp-seeker),"'");
        seeker=seektmp+1;   //todo: +delimiter size, instead of just 1
      }      
      //iterate 1 character, until the end of data 
      seektmp++;
    }  
  }
```

`_this` in the above code reffers to this reference from namespace that contains this function. `_this.http` is http request I'm using for long-polling.

I assign this one to the httpreques object:

```
this.http.onprogress = onprogressCallback;
```

Now the problem:

The **onprogress** enent is **not** called when I output small ammount of data once. The data is kept in some sort of buffer and a cannot reach them, however, I can see them in firebug.

However, if I keep spamming browser with useless data, such as load of `\n`, it works as it is supposed to:

```
while(condition && timeout condition) {
    if(data available) {
        echo $data."\n";
        flush();
    }
    else {
        echo "\n";  //Endless stream of \n keeps browser calling the onprogress event
        flush();
    }
}
```

But this really sucks. Such output is hard to debug and uses lots of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours.

What I could see is that the browser will not trigger the onprogress event unless they have received a minimum amount of data.  I don't know for sure what is this value for all browsers.  But for my case, I added blank space so the first message has a minimum size of 2048 characters.

I'm using something as simple as the following (PHP)

```
if (strlen($data) < 2048) {
    $data = str_pad($data, 2048 - strlen($data));
}
```

Note that your web server may strip the additional white spaces, so make sure it is not doing that if you didn't see the additional white spaces in the browser.